# Newly created cloth sim does not follow parented object

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm having a weird problem with my cloth sim.

I have debuged for a few hours now and can't figure out whats going on.

I have parented an object to an empty and as soon as I apply a cloth sim the object stops following its parents movement.

While testing different things I noticed that an older animation which uses the same technique still works fine (Was created about a month ago). But as soon as I delete the sim and create a new one it stops working.

Knowing that i copied the working object to a default cube file with ctrl+c & ctrl+v and parented it to an empty. Everything worked like it should until I delete the sim and add a new one with the exact same settings.
After that I applied a cloth sim to the default cube and also parented it to the empty.

Result is one object working properly and one not following its parent at all.

The sim of the cube is working. If it has gravity it falls down and colides with other objects. But it will not follow its parent no matter what i try.

This also only seems to effect cloth sims. Softbody

I have tested different Blender versions ranging from 3.0 - 3.2, reset to default, use a windows recovery point, deleted the blender config folder and a lot more but nothing changed. Has anybody an idea what is going on?

Her is a gif of my current test setup

[image: sim parenting example]

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Check your pin groups.

No idea how I repeated this error over and over and over again.
I always only created a pin group but never assigned any vertecies to it.

So here is another usefull tip. If you are tired and can't find the mistake go to sleep first. You will make the same mistakes over and over again.